# Why does using addition operator to add two sparse matrices doesn't work every time while the code is correct ( well partially as the e.g.s suggest)

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, ostream, istream, friend-function

Here , I wrote a code implementing addition operations on a Sparse Matrix using member function operator of a class . Now while the input functions work fine . The addtion function shows error with normal elements but works fine with diagonal elements . and the elements in the first row . I have pasted my code and my output screenshots below . Any suggestions whatsover whould be very helpful in solving the problem .

```
**My Code** 

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

  class Element{

  public:
  int i ;
  int j ;
  int x;
   };

 class Sparse
{
  private:
int m ;
int n;
int num;
Element *ele;

  public:
   
 Sparse(int m,int n,int num)
{
    this->m = m;
    
    this->n = n;
    
   this->num = num;
    
 ele = new Element[this->num];
  }
   ~Sparse()
  {
    delete []ele;
   }
  Sparse operator+(Sparse &s);

 friend  istream & operator >>(istream &is,Sparse &s);

friend ostream & operator << (ostream &os,Sparse &s);
   };

  Sparse Sparse::operator+(Sparse &s)
     {
    int i ,j,k;

    if (m!=s.m || n!=s.n)
        return Sparse(0,0,0);
    Sparse *sum  = new Sparse(m,n,num+s.num);
    i=j=k=0;
    while (i<num && j<s.num)
   
   {
   if (ele[i].i<s.ele[j].i)
   
 sum->ele[k++]=ele[i++];

 else if (ele[i].i > s.ele[j].i)
  
 sum->ele[k++]=s.ele[j++];

    else
  {
 if (ele[i].j<s.ele[j].j)
    
      sum->ele[k++]=ele[i++];

 else if (ele[i].j > s.ele[j].j)
       
       sum->ele[k++]=s.ele[j++];

else
{
 sum->ele[k]=ele[i];
   
  sum->ele[k++].x=ele[i++].x+s.ele[j++].x;
  }
 
     }

   }

  for (;i<num;i++)

 {
    sum->ele[k++] = ele[i];
 }

   for (;j<s.num;j++)

 {
    sum->ele[k++] = s.ele[i];
 }

 sum->num = k;

 return *sum ;

 }


istream & operator >>(istream &is,Sparse &s)
{
    cout << "Enter non-zero Elements" << endl ;
    for (int i = 0;i<s.num ;i++)
    {
        cin >> s.ele[i].i >> s.ele[i].j >> s.ele[i].x;
    }
    return is;

}

ostream & operator << (ostream &os,Sparse &s)
{
    int k = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<s.m; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<s.n; j++)
        {
            if (s.ele[k].i == i && s.ele[k].j == j)
                
             cout << s.ele[k++].x << " " ;
            
              else
                
              cout << "0 " ;
       
              }
        
           cout << endl ;
    }

    return os ;

   }



  int main()

 {

 Sparse s1(5,5,5);

 Sparse s2(5,5,5);

 cin >> s1;

  cin >> s2;

Sparse sum = s1+s2 ;

cout << "First Matrix " << endl << s1 ;

cout << "Second Matrix" << endl << s2 ;

cout << "Sum Matrix " << endl << sum ;

 return 0 ;
```

}

Output I : ( works correct )

```
  Enter non-zero Elements 
  0 0 5
  1 1 4
  2 2 3
  3 3 5 
  4 4 8
  Enter non-zero Elements 
  0 1 8
  1 1 4
  1 2 5 
  1 3 9
  2 1 6
  First Matrix
  5 0 0 0 0
  0 4 0 0 0
  0 0 3 0 0
  0 0 0 5 0
  0 0 0 0 8
  Second Matrix
  0 8 0 0 0
  0 4 5 9 0
  0 6 0 0 0 
  0 0 0 0 0 
  0 0 0 0 0
  Sum Matrix
  5 8 0 0 0
  0 8 5 9 0
  0 6 3 0 0
  0 0 0 5 0
  0 0 0 0 8
```

Output II :(shows error)

```
  enter non-zero elements
  0 2 3
  1 3 4
  2 4 6
  3 2 8
  4 1 9
  enter non-zero elements 
  0 2 6
  1 4 2
  2 1 6
  3 2 8
  4 1 4
  First Matrix
  0 0 3 0 0
  0 0 0 4 0
  0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 8 0 0
  0 9 0 0 0
  Second Matrix
  0 0 6 0 0
  0 0 0 0 2
  0 6 0 0 0
  0 0 8 0 0
  0 4 0 0 0
  Sum Matrix
  0 0 9 0 0
  0 0 0 4 0
  0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: please include input and output in the question. Please do not use images for text

Comment: please fix intendation of the code. Reading the code makes me dizzy

Comment: Read about "the rule of three".

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: You need to write a copy constructor and copy assignment operator for you class.

Comment: "doesn't work every time" and "the code is correct" are contradictory :-)

Comment: Hello , Please do check the google drive link for the screenshots . Stack overflow is not permitting me to  insert  img files .

Comment: @Quenti_20 People with a rudimentary interest in security don't look at google drive links from internet strangers. And your output is text, so there is absolutely no reason at all to take pictures of it.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the clarification , I am changing it ASAP .

Comment: @molbdnilo as u can see I removed the drive links  and included the text outputs . Please provide  me a possible explanation to this error also if u can a possible fix would be of great help .

Comment: A sidenote, if you absolutely think a screenshot is required to explain your situation, and the site doesn't allow you to post picture, you should post it to a image hosting site, like imgur.

Comment: dude, its perfectly fine now , just help me out here huh

Comment: Read the duplicate question and its answers.